# One Provisioning Profile for multiple apps?

Tags: profile

I am really confused with ios provisioning profile.  Can I use one Development Provisioning Profile for multiple apps? Same question for Distribution Provisioning Profile.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same certificates for multiple apps.

It may seem complicated, but once you look at it, it's not so bad. Here's the breakdown:

The development provisioning profile gives you the opportunity to test apps you create (any) until you try to push it to Apple. When you do that, the distribution profile comes into play. Essentially, it connects any apps you produce with your App Store storefront.